# Apple Configurator refreshes as soon as it finished

Tags: apple-configurator

I've got several iPads which I manage with Configurator. Since the 9.2 update when I plug in an iPad and refresh it, as soon as Configurator finishes refreshing the device, it starts over.

The process is basically:

1. Check iOS
2. Wipe device and reinstall
3. Install apps
4. Go to 1 and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem so I thought I'd share my solution:

After the device goes to refresh again, manually stop the refresh. Once you are able to clear the refresh screen and see the settings for that device, it should refresh correctly in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect answer, but it kind of works, and at least keeps the device from refreshing forever.

Under Preferences > General you can uncheck the box for Automatically Refresh when a supervised devised is connected:

This means you do have to manually click on each device to start the refresh process, however that is at least a bit preferable to having the device refresh interminably.